# codeigniter 403 override status

Tags: php, codeigniter

i know this question has been asked before. But completely there is no any good answer for this problem.

i was using `CSRF security` and completely know how to use it. if the token is not valid, the `csrf` will return me like

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> The action you have requested is not allowed.

and in `Security.php` there is a function how the status was set

```
public function csrf_show_error()
{
    show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.', 403);
}
```

kindly, i need to custom the the error page.

like in `config` if we set `$route['404_override'] = 'Page_error';`
it would show the `Page_error` what we have set before.

is there any case how to override the `403` ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

All built-in error pages use templates, which are located under *application/views/errors/* - you can edit those to change the appearance.

The CSRF error page in particular uses the 'error_general' template.

Can't use a controller for anything but the 404 page though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handled this. I created a MY_Security.php file in application/core with this PHP code:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Security extends CI_Security{

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function csrf_show_error(){
    if((!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'))
      exit(json_encode(array(//put your array elements here)));
    else
      show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.', 403);
  }

}

?>
```